# Azure Website Memory Usage - what's OK

Tags: memory, azure

I have been trying to determine what is the best instance/size combination for 21 sites on Azure Websites due to what I think is memory pressure. CPU is not an issue < 3%.

I have tried 1 medium and 1/2 smalls. Medium improved overall performance by about 15ms response time on the busiest site (per New Relic). Probably because it double the cores (and memory).

Using the new preview portal's memory quote module:

1 or 2 smalls runs about 80%-90% average memory
1 medium runs about 70%

That makes no sense considering the medium is double the memory. Is the larger memory availability not forcing the GC to run as often on the medium instance?

What % memory can an instance run and it not impact performance. 
Is 80-90 OK on the small instance?

Will adding instances to smalls help a memory problem since it basically just creates the same setup across all the instances and will eventually use up the same amount?

I have not been able to isolate any issues on performance on any of the 21 sites, but I don't want a surprise if I am running too close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this for some user edification. It seems that the ~80% range is normal and is just using "what's available." No perf issues or failures ever.

So if you come across this and are worries about the high memory usage, you'll need to keep an eye on it to determine if it's just normal or if you have memory leak.

I know, crappy answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the sites on a smaller instance and set auto-scale to ramp when it gets to high CPU.  Monitor how often it needs to scale and if it scales often just switch to a larger instance size permanently.

Comment: CPU averages out at 3% whether small or medium; no issues on CPU. It's all memory.